# How to read the content of text files when these are inside different folders and mixed with other types of files, using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder (Auto_Benchmark) which has many folders inside (InceptionV1, MobilenetV2, InceptioV4, etc). Each of these folders has 3 types of files: .txt, .jpg, .tflite. You can see IMAGE_1 for better understanding.

I want to call ONLY the .txt files and display their content.

The code "CODE_1" shows ONLY the path of the .txt files but not the content. And when I call the code like in "CODE_2" it shows ONLY 1 of the .txt files.

Why is it not working? How can I make the code read the 3 .txt files?

IMAGE_1
[image]

CODE_1

```
import os
from PIL import Image 


rootdir = os.getcwd()
#print(rootdir, "\n")


def load_labels(path_label, encoding='utf-8'):
    with open(path_label, 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        if not lines:
            return {}

        if lines[0].split(' ', maxsplit=1)[0].isdigit():
            pairs = [line.split(' ', maxsplit=1) for line in lines]
            return {int(index): label.strip() for index, label in pairs}
        else:
            return {index: line.strip() for index, line in enumerate(lines)}



if __name__ == '__main__': 
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            #print(filepath, "\n")


            if filepath.endswith(".txt"):
                path_label=filepath
                print(path_label)

                load_labels(path_label)
```

```
C:\Users\Projects\Classification\Auto_benchmark\Auto_benchmark\inception_v1\imagenet.txt
C:\Users\Projects\Classification\Auto_benchmark\Auto_benchmark\inception_v4\label.txt
C:\Users\Projects\Classification\Auto_benchmark\Auto_benchmark\mobilenet_v2\mobilenet.txt
```

CODE_2

```
load_labels(path_labels)
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the above result of code2 must showing the contents of `mobilenet.txt` ,right?

Comment: Code 1, function: `load_labels` is returning some dict type, why you are not capturing and printing in main function?

Comment: Yes, it is mobilenet.txt. I have written ```load_labels(path_label)``` in the main function, but still shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I am capturing and printing the files in the main function.

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            #print(filepath, "\n")


            if filepath.endswith(".txt"):
                print(filepath)

                labels=load_label(filepath)
                print(labels)
```

```
C:\Users\Projects\Classification\Auto_benchmark\Auto_benchmark\inception_v1\imagenet.txt
{0: 'background', 1: 'tench, Tinca tinca', 2: 'goldfish, Carassius auratus', 3: 'great white shark, white shark, man-eater, man-eating shark, Carcharodon carcharias', 4: 'tiger shark, Galeocerdo cuvieri', 5: 'hammerhead, hammerhead shark', 6: 'electric ray, crampfish, numbfish, torpedo', 7: 'stingray', 8: 'cock', 9: 'hen', 10: 'ostrich, Struthio camelus', 11: 'brambling, Fringilla montifringilla'} 

C:\Users\Projects\Classification\Auto_benchmark\Auto_benchmark\inception_v4\label.txt
{0: 'label', 1: 'label', 2: 'label'} 

C:\Users\Projects\Classification\Auto_benchmark\Auto_benchmark\mobilenet_v2\mobilenet.txt
{0: "Haemorhous cassinii (Cassin's Finch)", 1: 'Aramus guarauna (Limpkin)', 2: 'Rupornis magnirostris (Roadside Hawk)', 3: 'Cyanocitta cristata (Blue Jay)', 4: "Cyanocitta stelleri (Steller's Jay)", 5: 'Balearica regulorum (Grey Crowned Crane)', 6: 'Pyrocephalus rubinus (Vermilion Flycatcher)', 7: 'Recurvirostra americana (American Avocet)', 8: 'Ardeotis kori (Kori Bustard)', 9: 'Pica nuttalli (Yellow-billed Magpie)', 10: 'Perisoreus canadensis (Gray Jay)'}
```