# How to solve the "UnboundLocalError" when there are many functions and different types of files?

Tags: python-3.x

My question is related to this other question: 
[How to read the content of text files when these are inside different folders and mixed with other types of files, using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61825174/how-to-read-the-content-of-text-files-when-these-are-inside-different-folders-an?noredirect=1#comment109354949_61825174)

I am modifying the code that is in here: [Classify_image with Coral dev board](https://github.com/google-coral/tflite/blob/master/python/examples/classification/classify_image.py)
It does the following:

- It receives the path of an AI algorithm (a .tflite file aka model),
- the path of an image (a .jpg file aka input) to be classified and
- the path of the labels (a .txt file aka labels).
- Classifies the image and prints performance results and the timing.

But the path to all these files has to be inserted manually. Like this:

```
python3 classify_image.py \
 --model models/mobilenet_v2_insect/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_insect_quant_edgetpu.tflite \
 --labels models/mobilenet_v2_insect/inat_insect_labels.txt \
 --input images/insect.jpg
```

I want to execute many models (.tflite files). Each model has different labels (.txt files). And each model requires different images to be classified (.jgp files).
So basically I want the script to execute many models sequentially. I will just put the files in different directories (like the previous question that it is linked).
At the end I want to make a plot like this:

[image]

So far I have done this:

```
count = 2

rootdir = os.getcwd()
print(rootdir, "\n")


def load_label(path):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    ret = {} #creates an empty dictionary
    for row_number, content in enumerate(lines):
        pair = re.split(r'[:\s]+', content.strip(), maxsplit=1)

        #If there are only 2 elements AND the first one is a number:
        #a) then store the number in the dictionary (as a "key" and convert it to an integer)
        #and assign to it the other element as a "value"
        #If the first element is not a number, then store the row's number as a key. 
        if len(pair) == 2 and pair[0].strip().isdigit():
            ret[int(pair[0])] = pair[1].strip()
        else:
            ret[row_number] = pair[0].strip()
    return ret


def make_interpreter(model_file):
  model_file, *device = model_file.split('@')
  return tflite.Interpreter(
      model_path=model_file,
      experimental_delegates=[
          tflite.load_delegate(EDGETPU_SHARED_LIB,
                               {'device': device[0]} if device else {})
      ])


def main():
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            #print(os.path.join(root, file), "\n")
            filepath = os.path.join(root, file)

            if filepath.endswith(".txt"):
                #print(filepath, "\n")
                labels = load_label(filepath)
                #print(labels)

            if filepath.endswith(".jpg"):
                #print(filepath, "\n")
                size = classify.input_size(interpreter)
                image = Image.open(filepath).convert('RGB').resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                classify.set_input(interpreter, image)


            if filepath.endswith(".tflite"):
                #print(filepath, "\n")
                interpreter = make_interpreter(filepath)
                interpreter.allocate_tensors()


            print('----INFERENCE TIME----')
            print('Note: The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes',
                  'loading the model into Edge TPU memory.')
            for _ in range(count):
                start = time.perf_counter()
                interpreter.invoke()
                inference_time = time.perf_counter() - start
                classes = classify.get_output(interpreter, top_k, threshold)
                print('%.1fms' % (inference_time * 1000))

            print('-------RESULTS--------')
            for klass in classes:
                print('%s: %.5f' % (labels.get(klass.id, klass.id), klass.score))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the error that I am getting:
[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

I do not know how to solve it. I read that the solution might be using a global variable. Or maybe creating another function.

Any insights are much appreciated.

#

EDIT

If I put "interpreter" as a global variable:

```
def main():
    global interpreter
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            #print(os.path.join(root, file), "\n")
            filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
```

The error that I get is:

```
----INFERENCE TIME----
Note: The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto_benchmark_out.py", line 89, in <module>
    main()
  File "auto_benchmark_out.py", line 77, in main
    interpreter.invoke()
NameError: name 'interpreter' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `os.walk` is iterating over the files in an unspecified order, which [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk) mentions. As such, looks like it's picking an order in which the `.tflite` file doesn't get walked before `interpreter` is used, and thus the variable doesn't get initialized before being used.

There looks to be a similar bug with `classify`.

You could try using `glob.glob` to get all files that end in a specific extension, but with an intended order, eg

```
import glob
import os

def model_paths():
    # All tflite files in the current directory
    tflite_files = glob.glob("*.tflite")

    # initialize before use
    interpreter = make_interpreter(tflite_files[0])

    # Or automatically grab other files from the directory of each tflite:
    # This gets all tflite files in current directory and subdirectories
    for tflite_path in glob.glob("**/*.tflite"):
        current_directory = os.path.dirname(tflite_path)
        # look for other files

        # get the first text file in the same directory as the current tflite file
        text_glob = os.path.join(current_directory, "*.txt")
        text_path = glob.glob(text_glob)[0]

        # get the first jpg file that matches the same criteria
        jpg_glob = os.path.join(current_directory, "*.jpg")
        jpg_path = glob.glob(jpg_glob)[0]

        # do something with jpg_path, text_path, tflite_path
        yield tflite_path, text_path, jpg_path

def main():
    for tflite_path, text_path, jpg_path in model_paths():
        pass # insert your processing code here
```

Just use more reliable behavior than something that's inherently random (like `os.walk`)

Comment: Do I have to use "glob" for each of the files? ```glob.glob("*.txt")``` and glob.glob("*.jpg")?

Comment: That depends. If I'm understanding correctly, you have many directories, each with a `.tflite, .jpg, .txt` file that you want to process?

Comment: yes. There are many. You can check the question that I have linked. There is an image explaining the directories.

Answer (score 1):

[`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) uses [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) and this yields entries in arbitrary order. Your code relies on a `.tflite` file being yielded before the image files but this is not guaranteed. In case you imposed some ordering yourself (like lexicographical ordering) you can still iterate over `sorted(files)`, i.e.:

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in sorted(files):
```